# Mount AUFS pooled volume on boot (persistent / permanent)

Tags: boot, 14.04, mount, fstab, automount

I have mounted aufs with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/mnt/disk1=rw:/mnt/disk2=rw -o sum -o udba=reval -o create=pmfs none /mnt/virtual
```

It seems tow ork as expected so far with files from both disks appearing in virtual directory. The issue is that it gets unmounted on reboot. How do I mount it permanently so it remains after reboot?

I don't think it can be done in fstab as it's only for physical devices or so it seems. What is the correct way of  achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the line in `/etc/rc.local` should do the trick.